# How to extract characters from a string stored as json data and place them in dynamic number of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of string in `SQL Server` that stores `JSON` data with all the braces and colons included.

My problem is to extract all the key and value pairs and store them in separate columns with the key as the column header. What makes this challenging is that every record has different number of `key/value` pairs.

For example in the image below showing 3 records, the first record has 5 key/value pairs- `EndUseCommunityMarket of 2`, `EndUseProvincial Market of 0`, and so on. The second record has 1 key/value pair, and the third record has two key/value pairs.

[image]

If I have to show how I want this in excel it would be like:

[image]

I have seen some SQL code examples that does something similar but for a fixed number of columns, unlike this one it varies for every record.

Please I need a SQL statement that can achieve this as I am working on thousands of records.

Below is this data copied from `sql server`:

```
catch_ext
{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"EndUseEaten":1}}
{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"EndUseCommunityMarket":3}}
{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"","EndUseCommunityMarket":2}}
{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"mix reef fis","EndUseEaten":31}}
{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"10 fish with a total of 18kg","EndUseCommunityMarket":0,"EndUseProvincialMarket":0,"EndUseUrbanMarket":8,"EndUseEaten":1,"EndUseGivenAway":1}}
{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"mix reef fis","EndUseEaten":18}}
```

Comment: Are you able to say, what is the maximum number of columns from a single JSON value possible?

Comment: Some hints: Please do not poste pictures. Better is to paste the data, which allows us to take this into a test environment with *copy and paste*. Nobody wants to type this in. Best was a [mcve]. And please add your sql server's version. JSON support was added not before v2016. My suggestion: Provide to examples of JSON to see your issue in principles. Find a solution for two will help you to find a solution for many.

Comment: @DineshDB there can be at most 6 key/value pairs so 6 columns

Comment: @Shnugo I have added raw sql server data at the end of my question above to allow you to copy and paste into a test environment

Comment: @eloga, Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you don't want to dynamically create a table, instead you probably want to create a property mapping table.  Here is a quick overview of the design.

```
Object table -- this stores the base information about your object
============
ID            -- unique id field for every object.
Name

Property types table -- this stores all the property types
====================
Property_Type_ID -- unique type id
Description      -- describes property

Object2Property -- stores the values for each property
===============
ObjectID -- the object
Property_Type_ID -- the property type
Value -- the value.
```

Using a model like this lets your properties be as dynamic as you wish but you don't have to create columns dynamically -- something that is hard and error prone.

using your specific example the tables would look like this

```
OBJECT 
ID     NAME
1      WHAOO
2      RED SNAMPPER
3      KAWAKAWA

Property Types
ID     DESC
1      EndUseCommunityMarket
2      EndUseProvincialMarket 
3      EndUseUrbanMarket
4      EndUseEaten
5      EndUseGivenAway
6      Comment

Map
ObjID   TypeID   Value
1        1       2  
1        2       0
1        3       0
1        4       0
1        5       0
2        2       50
3        3       8
3        5       1
```

Comment: I do not want to create tables from design, all i want is a sql that query this table, and transform the data in this specific column(catch_ext) by putting them in separate columns named after the key names. For example from the data I just added to my question above, the column names would be EndUseEaten, EndUseCommunityMarket, SpeciesComment, EndUseCommunityMarket, etc..and the values are in quotes after the colons eg 1,3, mix reef fis,...something like the excel image also shown in my question.

Comment: I understand what you want -- I'm suggesting this is the better way to do it.  ESP. if you don't have a max number of columns (which you didn't when I wrote this answer.)  If you do have a max number of columns -- then it is not dynamic.  Then it is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

## A. ROWS

Dynamic columns are a lot like rows.

You could use [`OPENJSON (Transact-SQL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#example-4---combine-relational-rows-and-json-elements-with-cross-apply)

```
DECLARE @json2 NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"10 fish with a total of 18kg","EndUseCommunityMarket":0,"EndUseProvincialMarket":0,"EndUseUrbanMarket":8,"EndUseEaten":1,"EndUseGivenAway":1}}';

SELECT [key], value
FROM OPENJSON(@json2,'lax $.NfdsFadMonitoring')
```

Output

```
key value
SpeciesComment  10 fish with a total of 18kg
EndUseCommunityMarket   0
EndUseProvincialMarket  0
EndUseUrbanMarket   8
EndUseEaten 1
EndUseGivenAway 1
```

## Your inputs

```
CREATE TABLE ForEloga (Id int,Json nvarchar(max));

Insert into ForEloga Values 
(1,'{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"EndUseEaten":1}}'),
(2,'{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"EndUseCommunityMarket":3}}'),
(3,'{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"","EndUseCommunityMarket":2}}'),
(4,'{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"mix reef fis","EndUseEaten":31}}'),
(5,'{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"10 fish with a total of 18kg","EndUseCommunityMarket":0,"EndUseProvincialMarket":0,"EndUseUrbanMarket":8,"EndUseEaten":1,"EndUseGivenAway":1}}'),
(6,'{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"mix reef fis","EndUseEaten":18}}');

SELECT Id, [key], value
FROM ForEloga CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Json,'lax $.NfdsFadMonitoring')
```

### Output

```
Id  key value
1   EndUseEaten 1
2   EndUseCommunityMarket   3
3   SpeciesComment  
3   EndUseCommunityMarket   2
4   SpeciesComment  mix reef fis
4   EndUseEaten 31
5   SpeciesComment  10 fish with a total of 18kg
5   EndUseCommunityMarket   0
5   EndUseProvincialMarket  0
5   EndUseUrbanMarket   8
5   EndUseEaten 1
5   EndUseGivenAway 1
6   SpeciesComment  mix reef fis
6   EndUseEaten 18
```

---

## B. COLUMNS: CROSS APPLY WITH `WITH`

If you know all possible properties then I recommend `CROSS APPLY` with `WITH`as shown in *Example 3 - Join rows with JSON data stored in table cells using CROSS APPLY* in [OPENJSON (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#example-3---join-rows-with-json-data-stored-in-table-cells-using-cross-apply).

> ```
> SELECT store.title, location.street, location.lat, location.long  
> FROM store  
> CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(store.jsonCol, 'lax $.location')   
> WITH (
>      street varchar(500),
>      postcode  varchar(500) '$.postcode',  
>      lon int '$.geo.longitude', 
>      lat int '$.geo.latitude'
> ) AS location
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #JsonValue(sp_name VARCHAR(100),catch_ext VARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO #JsonValue VALUES ('WAHOO','{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"EndUseEaten":1}}')
INSERT INTO #JsonValue VALUES ('RUBY SNAPPER','{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"EndUseCommunityMarket":3}}')
INSERT INTO #JsonValue VALUES ('KAWAKAWA','{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"","EndUseCommunityMarket":2}}')
INSERT INTO #JsonValue VALUES ('XXXXXXXX','{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"mix reef fis","EndUseEaten":31}}')
INSERT INTO #JsonValue VALUES ('YYYYYYYY','{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"10 fish with a total of 18kg","EndUseCommunityMarket":0,"EndUseProvincialMarket":0,"EndUseUrbanMarket":8,"EndUseEaten":1,"EndUseGivenAway":1}}')
INSERT INTO #JsonValue VALUES ('ZZZZZZZZZZ','{"NfdsFadMonitoring":{"SpeciesComment":"mix reef fis","EndUseEaten":18}}')
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT sp_name
    ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]='EndUseCommunityMarket' THEN Value END),'')EndUseCommunityMarket
    ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]='EndUseProvincialMarket' THEN Value END),'')EndUseProvincialMarket
    ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]='EndUseUrbanMarket' THEN Value END),'')EndUseUrbanMarket
    ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]='EndUseEaten' THEN Value END),'')EndUseEaten
    ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]='EndUseGivenAway' THEN Value END),'')EndUseGivenAway
FROM(
    SELECT sp_name, [key], value
    FROM #JsonValue CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(catch_ext,'$.NfdsFadMonitoring')
    )D
GROUP BY sp_name
```

**Output:**

```
sp_name       EndUseCommunityMarket EndUseProvincialMarket EndUseUrbanMarket EndUseEaten EndUseGivenAway
------------- --------------------- ---------------------- ----------------- ----------- ---------------
KAWAKAWA      2                                                                          
RUBY SNAPPER  3                                                                          
WAHOO                                                                        1           
XXXXXXXX                                                                     31          
YYYYYYYY      0                     0                      8                 1           1
ZZZZZZZZZZ                                                                   18
```

Hope this will help you.